# В consol.log не выводится часть массива (Angular)

Tags: массивы, angular

Имеется глобальный сервис, внутри которого хранятся переменные и методы. Если проверить отдельные переменные (массивы), то они отображаются в консоли. Но среди всех переменных есть два массива (parts и categories), которые не отображаются отдельно (показывает пустой массив). При этом если проверить содержимое всего  сервиса через console.log можно увидеть всё, что есть внутри (в том числе и те массивы, которые по отдельности не отображаются).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код сервиса:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalSeviceService {
animals: Animal[] = [];
  genders: Gender[] = [];
  myAnimal: MyAnimal = {animal_id: 0, gender_id: 0};
  menu_items: Menu[] = [];
  categories: Category[] = [];
  parts: Part[] = [];
  actual_categ_id: number;
  non_changeable_parts_svg = []; 
  constructor_resp: any;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }
transferGenderId(b){
    this.myAnimal.gender_id = b;
  }

  transferConstructorData(anim_id, gender_id){
    this.http.get<Category[]>('http://localhost:8000/constructor_page?anim_id=' + anim_id
       + "&gender_id=" + gender_id)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.constructor_resp = response;
        this.categories = this.constructor_resp.constructor_page['categ_parts'];
        this.parts = this.constructor_resp.constructor_page['parts'];
        let j;
        let i = 0;
        for (j in this.categories) {
          if (this.categories[j].changeable){
            i ++;
            if (i === 1){
              this.categories[j].css_categ_active = true;
            }
            else {
              this.categories[j].css_categ_active = false;
            }
          }
        }
      });
}

}
```

Пробую выводить в консоли внутри компонента:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { PetComponent } from '../pet/pet.component';
import {GlobalSeviceService, Part} from '../services/global-sevice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-constructor-page',
  templateUrl: './constructor-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./constructor-page.component.scss']
})
export class ConstructorPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public globalService: GlobalSeviceService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.globalService.parts);
    console.log(this.globalService);
  }
}
```

anim_id и gender_id берутся от выбора пользователя.

В общем, если у вас есть предположение, почему не отображаются массивы в консоли, буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Возле объекта в консоли есть буква i в синем квадрате, прочитайте, что там написано

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//this.parts = this.constructor_resp.constructor_page['parts'];
this.parts.push.apply(this.parts, this.constructor_resp.constructor_page['parts']);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это сработало.

Comment: @KazarinovYanek Пожалуйста. Успехов. Надеюсь, понятно - почему. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Но при этом если я сделаю console.log(this.globalService.parts.length); то будет показан 0 (нуль). как взять длину массива в этом случае? Я имею ввиду, что массив в консоли тепеь есть, но его длина почему то все равно нулевая

Comment: @KazarinovYanek Длина массива выводится нулевая в момент вызова `console.log(...length);`, потому что в консоль просто пишется число. При вызове `console.log(this.globalService.parts);` консоль запоминает ссылку на массив и показывает его текущее (обновленное) состояние уже после того, как в массив были добавлены элементы.